# Postgresql setting next id to write to

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, postgresql-9.0

I recently migrated a database from mysql to pgsql 9.

But now when I try to create a new object (in django admin) it tells me that the id I'm trying to use (started at one and has increased each time I tried) is already used.

I'm guessing that there is a pointer or index which needs to be set to the last used id. Am I correct?

Comment: You can set the type of the column to `serial` and postgreSQL will create a sequence for you automatically.

Comment: I'm almost certain that it is, since the table is created by django.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709705/postgresql-nextval-generating-existing-values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you define your table, the PostgreSQL equivalent to 'auto_increment' is:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id    SERIAL,
    ...
);
```

If your table is already created (as I suspect it is), you can add this manually:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('foo_id_seq');
```

Note that if you want to stick with the default name that Pg *would have given you* use the following format for your sequence name:

```
<table name>_<column name>_seq
```

Thus in my example, `foo_id_seq`.

Comment: There was already a table and a sequence created by django. So I did not have to create the sequence and alter the table. But what worked was this: select setval('uploads_id_seq', 6965); (uploads being the table name)

Answer (score 2):

If the table was migrated and it uses serial to replace the mysql auto increment column, your data was probably migrated without incrementing the serial sequence.  Look up the postgresql `setval` function to set your sequence to a value above the highest existing key in your table.

Comment: I found it here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html I'm new to postgresql; can you show an example?

Comment: `SELECT setval('nameOfSequence', 42);`