# Django 1.4 primary key conflict after a bulk_create

Tags: database, django, conflict

I am using Django 1.4, with postgresql as the database, and I have the following model:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I am populating the django database with data from another database, using bulk_create,
with some code similar to:

```
Keyword.objects.bulk_create([Keyword(id=id, name=name) for id,name in [(1,"k1"),(2,"k2"),(3,"k3")] ])
```

The legacy data has the primary key already, and it is important to keep it this way.

The problem is that when I try to create new objects, Django will use primary keys starting from 1, and a conflict exception is thrown:

```
k = Keyword(name="k4")
k.save()
```

gives me the error

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sinbiota_keyword_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Is there a way to force Django to start the primary key increment at another value, or any way to solve this conflict?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting the next id in the auto increment logic of postgresql, outside of Django, using the `setval` command, similar to questions [Postgresql setting next id to write to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993442/postgresql-setting-next-id-to-write-to) and [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync).

In my example, i would have to execute in psql the command

```
select setval('keyword_id_seq', 3);
```

where `keyword_id_seq` is the name of the auto-increment sequence (by default, `<table_name>_<column_name>_seq'` ), and 6965 is the maximum id present in the table. That way,
the auto-increment starts from the next id (4 in this case) and no conflict happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default model behaviour of including an auto-incrementing primary key by adding your own `id` field and marking it as the primary key. E.g:

```
 class Keyword(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Docs: [Automatic Primary Keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

Comment: But I think that means that I would have to create my own primary key logic, which is really something I would not like to do. I actually found I solution here, will post it soon.